# Filtering JSON data in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a <strike>CSV</strike> JSON file of movie casts with 5000 items. The first item looks like this:

```
[{
    "cast_id": 5,
    "character": "John Carter",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea75",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 60900,
    "name": "Taylor Kitsch",
    "order": 0
}, {
    "cast_id": 20,
    "character": "Dejah Thoris",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813eab3",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 21044,
    "name": "Lynn Collins",
    "order": 1
}, {
    "cast_id": 7,
    "character": "Sola",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea79",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 2206,
    "name": "Samantha Morton",
    "order": 2
}, {
    "cast_id": 3,
    "character": "Tars Tarkas",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea6d",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 5293,
    "name": "Willem Dafoe",
    "order": 3
}, {
    "cast_id": 8,
    "character": "Tal Hajus",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea7d",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 19159,
    "name": "Thomas Haden Church",
    "order": 4
}, {
    "cast_id": 2,
    "character": "Matai Shang",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea69",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 2983,
    "name": "Mark Strong",
    "order": 5
}, {
    "cast_id": 4,
    "character": "Tardos Mors",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea71",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 8785,
    "name": "Ciar\u00e1n Hinds",
    "order": 6
}, {
    "cast_id": 9,
    "character": "Sab Than",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea81",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17287,
    "name": "Dominic West",
    "order": 7
}, {
    "cast_id": 10,
    "character": "Kantos Kan",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea85",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17648,
    "name": "James Purefoy",
    "order": 8
}, {
    "cast_id": 11,
    "character": "Powell",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea89",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17419,
    "name": "Bryan Cranston",
    "order": 9
}, {
    "cast_id": 12,
    "character": "Sarkoja",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea8d",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 6416,
    "name": "Polly Walker",
    "order": 10
}, {
    "cast_id": 13,
    "character": "Edgar Rice Burroughs",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea91",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 57675,
    "name": "Daryl Sabara",
    "order": 11
}, {
    "cast_id": 14,
    "character": "Stayman #1 / Helm",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea95",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 89830,
    "name": "Arkie Reece",
    "order": 12
}, {
    "cast_id": 15,
    "character": "Stayman #3",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea99",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 205278,
    "name": "Davood Ghadami",
    "order": 13
}, {
    "cast_id": 16,
    "character": "Lightmaster",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea9d",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 218345,
    "name": "Pippa Nixon",
    "order": 14
}, {
    "cast_id": 46,
    "character": "Thern #2",
    "credit_id": "584ef986c3a3682a940010d0",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1390394,
    "name": "James Embree",
    "order": 15
}, {
    "cast_id": 77,
    "character": "Thern #1",
    "credit_id": "58c68f82c3a3684114014f58",
    "gender": 0,
    "id": 1518112,
    "name": "Philip Philmar",
    "order": 16
}, {
    "cast_id": 47,
    "character": "Pretty Woman in NYC Doorway",
    "credit_id": "584f133992514107110024b8",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 1721985,
    "name": "Emily Tierney",
    "order": 17
}, {
    "cast_id": 48,
    "character": "Telegraph Clerk",
    "credit_id": "584f16d192514107000026a2",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1721992,
    "name": "Edmund Kente",
    "order": 18
}, {
    "cast_id": 49,
    "character": "Dalton",
    "credit_id": "584f1a94c3a3682a8d0026e7",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 118617,
    "name": "Nicholas Woodeson",
    "order": 19
}, {
    "cast_id": 50,
    "character": "Stable Boy",
    "credit_id": "584f1f2b9251410700002be9",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1722006,
    "name": "Kyle Agnew",
    "order": 20
}, {
    "cast_id": 51,
    "character": "Dix the Storekeeper",
    "credit_id": "584f28aec3a3683150000214",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 130129,
    "name": "Don Stark",
    "order": 21
}, {
    "cast_id": 52,
    "character": "Rowdy #1",
    "credit_id": "58580465c3a3683150056d0c",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 65716,
    "name": "Josh Daugherty",
    "order": 22
}, {
    "cast_id": 53,
    "character": "Rowdy #2",
    "credit_id": "58580cd89251411a4605f517",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1724736,
    "name": "Jared Cyr",
    "order": 23
}, {
    "cast_id": 37,
    "character": "Stockade Guard",
    "credit_id": "54e5a58d925141529c000f89",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 62082,
    "name": "Christopher Goodman",
    "order": 24
}, {
    "cast_id": 54,
    "character": "Sarah Carter",
    "credit_id": "585823dc925141594100c816",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 1367241,
    "name": "Amanda Clayton",
    "order": 25
}, {
    "cast_id": 170,
    "character": "Apache #1 (as Joe Billingiere)",
    "credit_id": "595ad40c9251410bfa04831e",
    "gender": 0,
    "id": 1844319,
    "name": "Joseph Billingiere",
    "order": 26
}
]
```

I only need the values of "name" in this file. For eg in this item it would be:

`Taylor Kitsch, Lynn Collins, Samantha Morton, Willem Dafoe, Thomas Haden Church, Mark Strong, Ciar Hinds, Dominic West, James Purefoy, Bryan Cranston, Polly Walker` etc.

Meaning values with key as "name".

How should I go about doing it?

Comment: That's not CSV, it's JSON

Answer (score 3):

What you've shown is a single *JSON array*, not a CSV. (File extensions don't matter to Python)

Parse the names from the objects in each JSON array row

```
import json

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        names = (x['name'] for x in json.loads(line))
        for name in names:
            print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to get all the names but the thing is they are all together one after the other meaning I cannot distinguish them based on the movies. Can I arrange them specific to a particular movie?

Comment: It's not clear what part of your data contains any information about a particular movie, but you could start by replacing the inner loop here with just `print(list(names))`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. You use the csv library to convert the rows into an array to iterate over. The ast library will turn a string into a dict/json object you can key into.

```
import ast
import csv
names = []

with open('csvFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        names.append(ast.literal_eval(row)[name])
        # or you could print(name) here.
```

Comment: Did you try this with a CSV file containing the row provided in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rudimentary example based on what you provided:

```
>>> movie =  [{"cast_id": 5, "character": "John Carter", "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea75", "gender": 2, "id": 60900, "name": "Taylor Kitsch", "order": 0}, {"cast_id": 20, "character": "Dejah Thoris", "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813eab3", "gender": 1, "id": 21044, "name": "Lynn Collins", "order": 1}]
>>> for i in movie:
...     print(i["name"])
...
Taylor Kitsch
Lynn Collins
```

Basically, this iterates over the different dictionaries in the list and then pulls the value associated with the `"name"` key.

More information is required to do this over an entire csv file, but this might get you started.

Comment: I have 5000 rows like this in an excel file. How could I get actors' name for all these 5000 rows?

Comment: Have you read the csv file into python yet? I encourage you to check out the [csv module for python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) if you haven't already; more specifically the `csv.reader` and `csv.DictReader` classes.

Comment: I am just going off what the OP gave. I don't have enough Karma to comment the OP for clarification... But you are right, looking at it now, that is a JSON file, not a CSV.

Comment: I have a csv file with multiple columns from which I have extracted single column of casts. This column has 5000 rows in the form of JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can directly make request with filter

```
{'$filter': ['name eq Lynn Collins']}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
my_list = [{
    "cast_id": 5,
    "character": "John Carter",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea75",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 60900,
    "name": "Taylor Kitsch",
    "order": 0
}, {
    "cast_id": 20,
    "character": "Dejah Thoris",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813eab3",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 21044,
    "name": "Lynn Collins",
    "order": 1
}, {
    "cast_id": 7,
    "character": "Sola",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea79",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 2206,
    "name": "Samantha Morton",
    "order": 2
}, {
    "cast_id": 3,
    "character": "Tars Tarkas",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea6d",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 5293,
    "name": "Willem Dafoe",
    "order": 3
}, {
    "cast_id": 8,
    "character": "Tal Hajus",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea7d",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 19159,
    "name": "Thomas Haden Church",
    "order": 4
}, {
    "cast_id": 2,
    "character": "Matai Shang",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea69",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 2983,
    "name": "Mark Strong",
    "order": 5
}, {
    "cast_id": 4,
    "character": "Tardos Mors",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea71",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 8785,
    "name": "Ciar\u00e1n Hinds",
    "order": 6
}, {
    "cast_id": 9,
    "character": "Sab Than",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea81",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17287,
    "name": "Dominic West",
    "order": 7
}, {
    "cast_id": 10,
    "character": "Kantos Kan",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea85",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17648,
    "name": "James Purefoy",
    "order": 8
}, {
    "cast_id": 11,
    "character": "Powell",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea89",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 17419,
    "name": "Bryan Cranston",
    "order": 9
}, {
    "cast_id": 12,
    "character": "Sarkoja",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea8d",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 6416,
    "name": "Polly Walker",
    "order": 10
}, {
    "cast_id": 13,
    "character": "Edgar Rice Burroughs",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea91",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 57675,
    "name": "Daryl Sabara",
    "order": 11
}, {
    "cast_id": 14,
    "character": "Stayman #1 / Helm",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea95",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 89830,
    "name": "Arkie Reece",
    "order": 12
}, {
    "cast_id": 15,
    "character": "Stayman #3",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea99",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 205278,
    "name": "Davood Ghadami",
    "order": 13
}, {
    "cast_id": 16,
    "character": "Lightmaster",
    "credit_id": "52fe479ac3a36847f813ea9d",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 218345,
    "name": "Pippa Nixon",
    "order": 14
}, {
    "cast_id": 46,
    "character": "Thern #2",
    "credit_id": "584ef986c3a3682a940010d0",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1390394,
    "name": "James Embree",
    "order": 15
}, {
    "cast_id": 77,
    "character": "Thern #1",
    "credit_id": "58c68f82c3a3684114014f58",
    "gender": 0,
    "id": 1518112,
    "name": "Philip Philmar",
    "order": 16
}, {
    "cast_id": 47,
    "character": "Pretty Woman in NYC Doorway",
    "credit_id": "584f133992514107110024b8",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 1721985,
    "name": "Emily Tierney",
    "order": 17
}, {
    "cast_id": 48,
    "character": "Telegraph Clerk",
    "credit_id": "584f16d192514107000026a2",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1721992,
    "name": "Edmund Kente",
    "order": 18
}, {
    "cast_id": 49,
    "character": "Dalton",
    "credit_id": "584f1a94c3a3682a8d0026e7",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 118617,
    "name": "Nicholas Woodeson",
    "order": 19
}, {
    "cast_id": 50,
    "character": "Stable Boy",
    "credit_id": "584f1f2b9251410700002be9",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1722006,
    "name": "Kyle Agnew",
    "order": 20
}, {
    "cast_id": 51,
    "character": "Dix the Storekeeper",
    "credit_id": "584f28aec3a3683150000214",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 130129,
    "name": "Don Stark",
    "order": 21
}, {
    "cast_id": 52,
    "character": "Rowdy #1",
    "credit_id": "58580465c3a3683150056d0c",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 65716,
    "name": "Josh Daugherty",
    "order": 22
}, {
    "cast_id": 53,
    "character": "Rowdy #2",
    "credit_id": "58580cd89251411a4605f517",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 1724736,
    "name": "Jared Cyr",
    "order": 23
}, {
    "cast_id": 37,
    "character": "Stockade Guard",
    "credit_id": "54e5a58d925141529c000f89",
    "gender": 2,
    "id": 62082,
    "name": "Christopher Goodman",
    "order": 24
}, {
    "cast_id": 54,
    "character": "Sarah Carter",
    "credit_id": "585823dc925141594100c816",
    "gender": 1,
    "id": 1367241,
    "name": "Amanda Clayton",
    "order": 25
}, {
    "cast_id": 170,
    "character": "Apache #1 (as Joe Billingiere)",
    "credit_id": "595ad40c9251410bfa04831e",
    "gender": 0,
    "id": 1844319,
    "name": "Joseph Billingiere",
    "order": 26
}
]

my_names = [temp_dict['name'] for temp_dict in my_list]
```